# Writing a macro that reads variables of different data types

Tags: c, macros, printf, scanf

I have the following task: "Write a macro `VARIN(a,fmt)` such that a macro call

```
VARIN(x,lf) is equivalent to
printf("\n x = "); scanf("%lf",&x);
and VARIN(i,d) is equivalent to
printf("\n i = "); scanf("%d",&i);
```

where x and i are some program variables of type double and int, respectively."

I'm at a loss. Been trying for hours, am still nowhere. How do I write a function or macro that reads variables from different data types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want C by your examples.
You want something like this:

```
#define VARIN( a, fmt ) printf( "\n " #a " = " ); scanf( "%" #fmt, &a );
```

The `#a` *stringifies* the variable to text.

```
int boo() {
    double x;
    VARIN( x, ld );
    char str[10];
    VARIN( str, s );
}
```

Should be usable like the above.